# how can I get Word.Section Range using office javascript api?

Tags: office365, office-js, add-in, word-addins

I want to get current Word Section range. where my cursor is clicked get there section rage.

this is like of Microsoft documentation

[Word.Section class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word/word.section?view=word-js-preview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [document.getSelection()](https://learn.microsoft.com/javascript/api/word/word.document?view=word-js-preview#word-word-document-getselection-member(1)) to get the range where the cursor is. Then on that range object, call [Range.parentBody](https://learn.microsoft.com/javascript/api/word/word.range?view=word-js-preview#word-word-range-parentbody-member). This will give you the body of the section that the cursor is in. Then on that body object use [Body.getRange("Whole")](https://learn.microsoft.com/javascript/api/word/word.body?view=word-js-preview#word-word-body-getrange-member(1)) to get the range of the whole section body.

Comment: please create an example here with word.run function

Comment: I want like a single page range which is in current selection

Comment: and please check this question [question link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77536373/22905514)