# how can I get `parentSectionOrNullObject` Range in word? using Office javascript Api?

Tags: javascript, office365, office-js, add-in, word-addins

I am using this but this is giveing error `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isNullObject')` when I am using breakpoint then this is give `selection.parentSectionOrNullObject` undefined.no idea why irs gives error.

[image: parentSectionOrNullObject = undefined image]
[image: error image]

```js
 async function getSectionRange() {
     try {
         await Word.run(async (context) => {
             const selection = context.document.getSelection();
             selection.load('parentSectionOrNullObject');

             await context.sync();

             if (!selection.parentSectionOrNullObject.isNullObject) {
                 const parentSection = selection.parentSectionOrNullObject;
                 const sectionRange = parentSection.getRange("Whole");

                 context.load(sectionRange, 'text');

                 await context.sync();

                 console.log('Section Range Text:', sectionRange.text);
             } else {
                 console.log('The selection is not within a section.');
             }
         });
     } catch (error) {
         console.error('Error: ', error);
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `selection` variable is a Range object. Range does not have a parentSectionOrNullObject property. That property is only found on the Body object. As I explained in my answer to your other question: [how can I get Word.Section Range using office javascript api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77530075/how-can-i-get-word-section-range-using-office-javascript-api/77532051?noredirect=1#comment136692583_77532051), you need to get the parent *body* of `selection` first.